# Full Backup got failed while reindexing

Tags: marklogic

We have two scheduled backups which are given below
1. Full backup with JA true - runs daily at 3AM. max-backup is set to 1
2. Incremental backup with JA true - run 4 hours 55 mins past the hour.

As a planned activity we added one custom dictionary and force reindex the whole database and did not disable the backups. Reindexing took longer as reindexing got disabled everytime the scheduled backup starts.
Reindexing took 32 hours to complete, after few days we found that the backup drive got exhausted due to space.

On debuggin it further we found that the full backup was on for the date on which the reindexing was triggered, after that there is no full backup (and the previous backup was not deleted) and due to JA true the journals were keep on writing to the backup directory.

We are not able to understand why the full backup got failed.

For example:
we ran the reindexing on 13th Sept at 8 AM and completed at 14th Sep, 4 PM
On 14th sept the full backup got failed and the previous backup was not deleted.

We found the issue after 7-8 days and found that only 13th sept date backup was present.

Comment: It is a little difficult to diagnose why your full backup failed without any details from log messages. There could be any number of reasons. There should be clues in the ErrorLog in the around the time of the failure. Look for any Error, Notice, or Warning message around that time and post in this question, or if you are able to, open a Support ticket with MarkLogic and they can help diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that incremental backups will track changes since the last backup, and reindexing is a large number of changes, so running incremental backups while reindexing could produce larger than expected files. It also sounds likely that the larger incremental backups may have reduced the disk space enough for their to be insufficient space for the next full backup.

Additionally, the previous backup was not deleted because the attempt at the full backup failed.  The previous backup will only be deleted once the new backup completes successfully.

[Backing Up and Restoring a Database](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore)